# Search a string for a wildcard year C++

Tags: c++, find, wildcard

I'm looping through a text file, reading each paragraph into a string. I want to process any paragraphs that contain a year, but if no year is found then I want to continue looping through the file. When a year is found, I want to know the index where that year was found.

I'm trying to avoid any boost or regex code for simplicity. I also assume that the only years of interest will be in the 1900s and 2000s, for simplicity. I tried the following code, but the wildcard characters were not working for some reason. Is is because wildcard characters do not work for numbers?

```
string sParagraph = "Aramal et al. (2011), Title";
int iIndex;

if (sParagraph.find("19??")!=string::npos)
    iIndex = sParagraph.find("19??");
else if (sParagraph.find("20??")!=string::npos)
    iIndex = sParagraph.find("20??");
else
    continue;
```

Comment: Wild card element? To my knowledge, no such thing exists.

Comment: C++ has [regular expressions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) that can help with that

Comment: `I'm trying to avoid any boost or regex code for simplicity`  You thought it were so simple that all you needed were question marks for wildcards?   By the time you get your "non-boost" or "non-regex" code to work correctly and consistently, you wind up with code that is worse than what you were trying to avoid using.

Comment: Lets also note that a true wildcard character would also match things that are not valid years.

Comment: @PaulMicKenzie Perhaps simplicity was the wrong word to use... I haven't used boost or regex code before, so I've been keeping with the familiar. It seemed simple enough logic that there would be a way without getting too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using regex or boost code you *might* be making your code more readable, but it will not be more simple.

A "simple" one-pass pseudo algorithm:

```
map<int, std::vector<int>> years;
String par = " ... "

//inefficient but didn't want to have to add more complicated code
//in the while loop. Just want to solution to be clear
int par_index = par.find_first_of("19"); 
if(par_index == string::npos) 
    par_index = par.find_first_of("20");
if(par_index == string::npos)
    //skip //No years in this paragraph

while(par_index < par.size()) {
    string year(par, par_index, 4);
    int year = atoi(year.c_str());  //or use C++11 stoi
    if(2100 < year && year >= 1900)
        years.at(year).push_back(par_index);
    par_index += 4;
}
```

This will create a map where the key is the year and the value is a vector of ints that represent the index that the year landed on.

Comment: This works great, thanks. I hadn't even thought to convert to an int.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just reread the question and noticed that this answer might be too irrelevant. Sorry if it is.

I was looking for something similar a couple days ago. My approach might be very (very very) inefficient: I looped through the entire string and used 'atoi()' to see whether each group of four characters was a year.

```
for (int i = 0; i < txt.length() - 3; i++)
{
    string t = txt.substr(i, 4); //Take a group of four characters.

    int year = atoi((char*)t.c_str());

    if (year > 1800 && year < 3000)
    {
        break;
    }
    else year = 0;
}
```

At the end, 'year' is either zero or an actual year.

Answer (score 0):

So of course you can do this. But it will not be simpler, it will be more complex.

Anyway, this is probably your best non-regex solution. It uses a `string::iterator` not a position:

```
string sParagraph = "Aramal et al. (2011), Title";
auto iIndex = adjacent_find(sParagraph.begin(), sParagraph.end(), [](char i, char j){return i == '1' && j == '9' || i == '2' && j == '0'; });
const auto end = next(sParagraph.end(), -3);

while (iIndex < end && (isdigit(static_cast<int>(*next(iIndex, 2))) == false || isdigit(static_cast<int>(*next(iIndex, 3))) == false)){
    iIndex = adjacent_find(next(iIndex, 4), sParagraph.end(), [](char i, char j){return i == '1' && j == '9' || i == '2' && j == '0'; });
}
```

To use this you'll need to check if you have iterated to `end`:

```
if(iIndex < end){
    continue;
}
```

Just for purpose of comparison, you can use a `regex_search` to determine if the year exists:

```
string sParagraph = "Aramal et al. (2011), Title";
smatch iIndex;

if (!regex_search(sParagraph, iIndex, regex("(?:19|20)\\d{2}"))){
    continue;
}
```

An [`smatch`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/smatch/) contains far more information and just a position, but if you want the index of the start of the year you can do: `iIndex.position()`

A common pitfall for people who are not familiar with the features of C++11 is to say: "I don't understand how to use this stuff, it must be more complicated than what I already know." And then go back to what they already know. Don't make that mistake, use the `regex_search`.

Comment: @WhiteFish Hmmm... I learned `regex`es in Perl. I don't know if there is a great reference for learning based in C++ yet. Microsoft has some info on it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727.aspx The most helpful thing to me now is: https://regex101.com/ It does a really good job of breaking out what the regex you've entered actually means.